# VBA one inputbox for multiple sub procedures

Tags: vba, excel

Hello i have this code my question is about inputbox. My inputbox is used for adressing to last folder where are my reports saved. But i want value of this inputbox (which is January 2018) also use in sub `spracovanie2` to safe worbook in which is this code written. How can i make one inputbox to work for two sub precodures. I don't want to wrie same value two times. Can i make it public somehow?
Please comment if you think i don't expressing myself clearly.

```
    Sub Spracovanie1()
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim wb2 As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range
Dim rng2 As Range
Dim mesiac_rok As String

mesiac_rok = InputBox("Mesiac/Rok")

Set wb = Workbooks.Open("????????\" & mesiac_rok & "\??????.xlsx")
Set ws = wb.Sheets("Check List Action plan Opr")
Set rng = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)

Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open("????????\" & mesiac_rok & "\??????.xlsx")
Set ws2 = wb2.Sheets("Check List Action plan Opr")
Set rng2 = ws2.Range("B4").CurrentRegion.Offset(1, 0)
    rng2.Resize(rng2.Rows.Count - 1).Copy Destination:=rng
    wb2.Close

Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open("????????\" & mesiac_rok & "\??????.xlsx")
Set ws2 = wb2.Sheets("Check List Action plan Opr")
Set rng = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
Set rng2 = ws2.Range("B4").CurrentRegion.Offset(1, 0)
    rng2.Resize(rng2.Rows.Count - 1).Copy Destination:=rng
    wb2.Close


Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open("????????\" & mesiac_rok & "\??????.xlsx")
Set ws2 = wb2.Sheets("Check List Action plan Opr")
Set rng = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
Set rng2 = ws2.Range("B4").CurrentRegion.Offset(1, 0)
    rng2.Resize(rng2.Rows.Count - 1).Copy Destination:=rng
    wb2.Close


Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open("????????\" & mesiac_rok & "\??????.xlsx")
Set ws2 = wb2.Sheets("Check List Action plan Opr")
Set rng = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
Set rng2 = ws2.Range("B4").CurrentRegion.Offset(1, 0)
    rng2.Resize(rng2.Rows.Count - 1).Copy Destination:=rng
    wb2.Close

Set wb2 = Workbooks("?????.xlsm")
Set ws2 = wb2.Sheets("Check List Action plan Opr")
Set rng2 = ws2.Range("B1")
    ws.UsedRange.Copy Destination:=rng2


wb.SaveAs Filename:=("????????\" & mesiac_rok & "\??????.xlsx)"
wb.Close
End Sub

Sub Spracovanie2()
'
    Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range
Dim LastRow As Long

    Set wb = Workbooks("Reporting AP Bwise source.xlsm")
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("Check List Action plan Opr")
    Set rng = ws.Range("B4").CurrentRegion
    Set ws2 = wb.Sheets("OPR Action plans_TEMP")

    rng.Copy Destination:=ws2.Range("A1")
    ws2.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.UnMerge


    LastRow = ws2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        ws2.Range("A1:AP" & LastRow).Sort Key1:=ws2.Range("N1:N" & LastRow), _
            Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes


    Set ws = wb.Sheets("OPEN AP")
         ws.UsedRange.ClearContents
    Set ws2 = wb.Sheets("CLOSED AP")
         ws2.UsedRange.ClearContents
end sub
```

Comment: A public Function perhaps?

Comment: @Kostas K. But that will only make string variable public no? but not this `mesiac_rok = InputBox("Mesiac/Rok")` or you know how to make it public also if yes please tell me cause i don't know how.

Comment: The function will show the inputbox and return its value.

Comment: @Kostas K. Sorry for the doubt you we're right I make the string variable public and it works for both subs. Thank you.

Comment: Good to hear. If both Subs are in the same module, mark the variable `Private` - no need for public scope.

Comment: @Kostas K. Will do thanks.

Comment: @KostasK. Do you want to put this in an Answer? Or do you feel the question should be Closed?

Comment: Not really an answer but a pointer, isn't it? :)